# ActionListening issue with DrawerLayout and RecyclerView in activity_main.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

I have a DrawerLayout and a RecyclerView. Only one seems "interactive" or only one is listening for a click.

The following is in regards to editing the activity_main.xml file.

With DrawerLayout appearing above the RecycleView, only the DrawerLayout is interactive. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYi0I.png

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.rajonbeckman.activityweather.MainActivity" >

    <include android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar" layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout android:id="@+id/drawer"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar">

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"-->
    <fragment android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
        android:name="com.rajonbeckman.activityweather.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

When RecycleView is on top of DrawerLayout, only RecycleView is clickable. https://i.stack.imgur.com/fin5K.gif

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.rajonbeckman.activityweather.MainActivity" >

    <include android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar" layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout android:id="@+id/drawer"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar">

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"-->
    <fragment android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
        android:name="com.rajonbeckman.activityweather.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This makes it seem like an actionListening issue. I'm new to android and would love some feedback. If you need anymore information or code, don't hesitate to ask. Thank you for your time.